# How can I add New List to my MailChimp Account By programming in PHP?

Tags: php, api, newsletter, mailchimp

I have mailchimp account, I would like to add new list to my mailchimp account using PHP Library for MailChimp.

I have coded the following for add new Group to the given list.

```
$mailChimp = new MCAPI($api_key);
$mailChimp->listInterestGroupAdd($mylistId, $group_name);
```

above code is use for Add new Group into the existing List.

Can I add New List, what is the method available to add new List?
Can I use like this?

```
$mailchimp->listAdd($listname);
```

Here is the documentation of Mailchimp API v1.3 and all the List related functions But I have not get any method which will allow us to add new List.

> http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/#listrelated

Comment: Any other method to add List also acceptable

Comment: Here is the current api documentation: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/#lists-methods

Comment: Yes I have found V2.0 Mailchimp API but I couldn't found out any method for adding new list.

Comment: Me neither, which is why I left it as a comment, not an answer! I was hoping I missed something. Contacting Mailchimp directly will give you the definitive answer you are looking for.

Comment: you are right I will try to contact directly MailChimp I hope it will be fine for me.

Comment: My Mail concern is to Synchronize the List Name Between My Site Admin Section and MailChimp.

Comment: If not, something like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/lists.html) might be another option.

Comment: SendGrid is looks good but MailChimp is already implemented and working fine so I don't think go for new API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can not be done using the API.

You can make list as that you wanted in web-app and also check the group to structure the list data.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the MailChimp v1.3 API is deprecated. You should use the newer [v2.0 version](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/). I checked the API Documentation. I couldn't find the function that you were looking for.

Comment: is there any function in V2.0 Version will use to add new List in my Mailchimp account?

Comment: looks like there is no call in the v2 for creating a list.